# How get SQLITE to buffer inserts?

Tags: sqlite

I'm creating a transaction explicitly using SQLITE, i.e.:

sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN", NULL, NULL, NULL);

do a bunch of inserts

sqlite3_exec(db, "END", NULL, NULL, NULL);

I expect the database to buffer the inserts between this pair until the END is hit, then flush it all to disk.

It doesn't seem to do this, instead flushing to disk at regular intervals.

I'm also noticing that I sometimes can't successfully execute a select statement on the same database from a different process, and I suspect it might be related to my transaction usage strategy. In these cases the select fails because of a LOCK or BUSY state on the db.

Does anyone know how to man-handle SQLITE so it buffers the inserts for better performance?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A transaction keeps SQLite from committing to the database file until the transaction is complete (or is rolled back), but it doesn't stop it from writing to the disc as it still needs to update the journal file.

You may be able to get around this by using an in memory database and then writing the in-memory database to your file-based database.  More info here: [In-Memory Databases](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

Also, SQLite's standard journal model supports either a single writer, or multiple readers, but not both, which is why you're getting a LOCK/BUSY state when you try to select.  To get around that you should look into using the WAL journal method instead of the rollback method. More info here: [Write-Ahead Logging](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/wal.html)